# Elasticsearch Python Django: How to limit the output text content and highlight the input keyword

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, full-text-search

This is my search function in views.py

```
def search(request, pk, slug):
    es = Elasticsearch()
    es_client = Elasticsearch(['http://127.0.0.1:9200'])
    print('called search')
    search_text = request.GET.get('qq')
    print('Search text: {}'.format(search_text))
    print('cluster id/ ealstic search index: {}'.format(pk))
    s = None
    count = 0

    try:
        if search_text:
            s = Search(index=str(pk)).using(es_client).query("match", content=search_text)
            response = s.execute()
            count = 0
            for hit in s:
                count += 1
                print(str(count) + ' - ' + str(hit.currnet_url))
                #print(hit.content)
            else:
                print('nothing more found')
        else:
            print('No text to search')
    
    except Exception as e:
        count = 0
        print('Exception caught')
        msg = 'Cluster is not ready to be searched'
        return render(request, 'base_app/cluster_search.html', {'warning':msg, 'count':count})
    
    return render(request, 'base_app/cluster_search.html', {'cluster':slug, 'hits':s, 'count':count})
```

This is how I am indexing data to Elasticsearch.

```
def elastic_indexer(text, depth, url, clusrer_id):
    
    es_client = Elasticsearch(['http://127.0.0.1:9200'])
    doc = {
        "date": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        "currnet_url": url,
        "depth": depth,
        "content": text
    }
    res = es_client.index(index= str(clusrer_id), doc_type="_doc", body=doc)
    print(res["result"])
```

This is the frontend template where the users input a text to search.

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Search" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<a href="{% url 'clusters' %}">Go Back</a>

<P style="font-size:17px;">You are searching in {{cluster.title}}</P>

<form method="GET" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" action="">Search</button>
    <input id="q" name="qq" type="text" placeholder="enter search text here" style="width: 500px;">
</form>

{% if hits %}
    <table>  
        {% for hit in hits %}
        <tr>
            <td>Hit: <a href="">{{hit.currnet_url}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content: {{hit.content}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <h3> No search result found </h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is returning everything, all the text stored in "content", how do I limit this to only the user's input text and only show limited characters before and after the input text? and including highlighting the input text? Please help me out

Example:
What it shows:

```
*User inputs text, assuming it's "django"*
hits: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Content: all of the scraped text stored in "content"
```

**What I want it to show:**

```
User inputs text, assuming it's "django"
hits: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Content: 10 words before "django" and 10 words after "django"
```